# Typescript enforce object string used from parent object like enum

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm working on an API wrapper for a lower level library which uses enums to map human readable keys to the under-the-hood values. In our API, I'd like to mask all of the underlying values in logging/etc so I want to only use the enum keys on our end. I'd like to dynamically create an object which takes the original enum and generates a new one where the keys/values are equal. I also would like to enforce the parent object keys are passed into parameters just like an enum, rather than allowing the string value used directly.

```js
enum Colors {
    red = '$r5',
    green = '$g2',
    lightBlue = '$b9',
    darkBlue = '$b1',
}

function getColor(color: Colors) {
    return color;
}


getColor(Colors.darkBlue); // passes
getColor('darkBlue'); // fails as expected

function createKeyEnum<E>(e: E): {[k in keyof E]: k extends keyof E ? k : never} {
    return Object.keys(e).reduce((p, v) => {
        (p as any)[v] = v;
        return p;
    }, {} as {[k in keyof E]: k extends keyof E ? k : never});
}

const NewColors = createKeyEnum(Colors);
type NewColors = keyof typeof NewColors;


// forward mapping
function getOldColor(color: NewColors) {
    return Colors[color];
}

// reverse mapping
function getNewColor(color: Colors) {
    const reverse: any = {};
    Object.entries(Colors).forEach(([k, v]) => reverse[v] = k);
    return reverse[color] as NewColors;
}

getOldColor(NewColors.darkBlue); // passes
getOldColor('darkBlue'); // passes, but should fail like an enum
const color = getNewColor(Colors.darkBlue);
// typeof color == 'red' | 'green' | 'lightBlue' | 'darkBlue'
// should be: typeof color == NewColors
```

Is this possible with any fancy typings, or are enums a purely under-the-hood magic that can't be replicated using other TS typings? In the example below, my NewColors types (understandably so) is just a union of the literal key strings. While this works - it does allow users to use the string value directly. How can I make it linked to the parent symbol NewColors and enforce the values are derived directly from it like an enum?

Comment: enums are static values. TypeScript has structural type system. Maybe you are looking for branding types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the object output by `createKeyEnum()` to have properties whose values are [*nominally typed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominal_type_system).  So while  `NewColors.darkBlue` might be equivalent to `"darkBlue"` at runtime, you want the compiler to see them as different, because they have different *names* or *declaration sites*.

By contrast, most of TypeScript's type system is [*structural*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system), where two types can be seen as compatible despite having different names or declaration sites.  There is a longstanding open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#202](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/202) asking for some official support for nominal typing.

As you've seen, [enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html) are one feature where there's a certain amount of nominal typing.  But you can't generate an enum programmatically, so this won't work for you directly.

---

What you *can* do is ["brand"](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#can-i-make-a-type-alias-nominal) a string literal type by [intersecting](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it with some nominal or nominal-ish type.  Such branding simulates nominal types in the type system.

Using an intersection means that the branded type will be seen as assignable to the string literal type, but not vice versa.  (So `NewColors extends 'red' | 'green' | 'lightBlue' | 'darkBlue'` should be true, but `'red' | 'green' | 'lightBlue' | 'darkBlue' extends NewColors` should be false).

Depending on the intersected type, you might need to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) inside `createKeyEnum()`'s implementation to convince the compiler that you actually have a value of that type.  After all, the actual value is just a string, and the whole point is for the compiler to complain when we use a string in place of the nominally typed value.  So some error suppression might be needed.

---

Let's imagine that we have a type alias called `Brand<T, U>` which brands `T` with some type that also depends on `U` (so that `Brand<"darkBlue", Colors>` and `Brand<"darkBlue", SomeOtherEnum>` would be incompatible with each other).  We can worry about how to define `Brand` below.  For now, let's just say we have it.

Then you could implement `createKeyEnum()` like this:

```
function createKeyEnum<E>(e: E) {
  class foo { private bar = 0 }
  return Object.keys(e).reduce((p, v) => {
    (p as any)[v] = v;
    return p;
  }, {} as { [K in keyof E]: Brand<K, E> }); // <-- need to assert here
}
```

And because you are intentionally going to make `NewColors` somewhat incompatible with `keyof typeof Colors`, you might need to explicitly widen the former to the latter when indexing into `Colors` to avoid errors:

```
function getOldColor(color: NewColors) {
  const k: keyof typeof Colors = color; // widen here
  return Colors[k]; // now we can use k as a key
}
```

This will give you the behavior you want:

```
getOldColor(NewColors.darkBlue); // passes
getOldColor('darkBlue'); // fails
const color = getNewColor(Colors.darkBlue);
// const color: NewColors
```

---

So, how should we implement `Brand`?  The easiest way is to use a "phantom" property:

```
type Brand<T, U> = T & { _tag: U };
```

This uses structural typing to simulate nominal typing.  Nothing stops someone from actually adding a `_tag` property, but it's pretty unlikely and bizarre to imagine someone circumventing the safety via `getOldColor(Object.assign("darkBlue", { _tag: Colors }))`.  If someone goes to such trouble, maybe you should let them do it.

---

If you really want to prevent that, you can use a `class` with [a `private` member](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#private):

```
declare class BrandClass<U> { private constructor(); private _tag: U };
type Brand<T, U> = T & BrandClass<U>
```

Since the `_tag` member is `private`, the compiler treats the `BrandClass` type as nominal, so you can't get a `BrandClass` instance without using the name `BrandClass`:

```
getOldColor(Object.assign("darkBlue", { _tag: Colors })); // error
```

And you can't actually construct it because the constructor is `private` also:

```
getOldColor(Object.assign("darkBlue", new BrandClass<typeof Colors>())); // error
```

This makes it nearly impossible for someone to produce a value that the compiler sees as `Brand<T, U>` without using a type assertion.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.3.5#code/KYOwrgtgBAwg9gGzgJwM5QN4CgpWcAEygF4oByAEmQFYyAaHKAc31BPIqYCZ7GEBLJgAsALgCEEYYO0oAjAJy9cBAIbIA1hKkyKsgIy8AvliwAzMCADGI-nBDNgI+EmQAKS4hQAuWJ7QBKTEZ8ETBkew8XAG4sYxMmR2cUVyS0ADpVDS1gfyioAHp8qAAHFVRUYFQsBKc-VzJMzUlgMlyCotMVfgR0MqhgAA9i4GtCEywQFQhK0stpMWQVEAIABSElkThobEYRAE9hqAWlggAeABU6KABVAD52c6gAMkwoAH0RFSYfa6hDGMY5isNjsUEs+BUImAAGlgHsAKLgCCneG3VzAHzwwLYXC4SwIMroUxwOCvYrIfgAN0h0lkanYAAY-oxcCEwvYAPKyABWIxEaXUcNQ6P8aXwBDAc1crmKV0pgWI9xxuNwMqgfSWe38AG1KQBddiUmIq1mOdklY24wxXDCGdXoDBQbXQqD8eyCvZwUxQeF6nzHZanaFXVF-XKMOJ4uyoERQABywAA7ql0KRwcAabCEUiUn5UOHcPtDgnk3n2EXgF740mU9qPVWK1WSym9QDGIUoMTkIm1EQICpisU3UxARZrLZ7DUOQgCKl3H4fM289iWWDo7H1D5697G96U+xIihLabQuFfC5UHXWxGTLgO-hKcA0NJ+4Ph6PgROHCIly55y4fBTFcVQ8EAYzwYBH2fHxNXYW1jygLleWsNJQBEClKlzC9RS7eEVEsIRpTrOU9QVe4HyfCpdQNUh1ALXE2TPCjn21Q9kANPpfxQVBLUjb9p1nOouPSRpsjaDtSnKSpGCnGc5waNQmikVo8g7TpuiqKMwNjNj2BqYSsO4jJFLEy0O1A8C2MXGs81vfi5LqJC+TSQlBBAVwACJROaDybXeT5vnPbiw38Ew4gmKYZnw+ZFmWGACXKFYKWpKEgkYAgRgJfAwQS9AA1nXLTjuMlkppNdtOQSVNjcNpySpMqPi+H4-ktCsjlis5Lhue5SEeF58viwkituOygXHUF00zOFEUgFE0QxH1gNxfFCU7EkSvq1K6WQRlmRVRjOR5ZyPWFHIxUISVgGlWUoHlEglVXVVintdUQC1ajDQQk9zWKBDrUwO0+kdZ1XXdOEq19f0OqDEN7kMei+Is2NhNTMEIShLMZogQyAlag5pBR8t8abGyLzrcGd2J70UevOy1JQHtkD7AchxAEdcDGkFJ0cAS5ys6tS2woIQPXKBNzFimoF3IK0APPwEIOmXL3Ua9cD4+9IMol8WffDmxy578DP5oDheW0XmIqGC3rg-5VyclC0Iw4UgLSXD8MI1xiNu0j7ogqCqP1dg6IVs0mM1li2I49AUd4uzZMEv8UeMrJmnEopJIqTT7IT5IFJT5S087LoekYJG1xcPTHAMlNk6UnIzKKMv+ZRuOeYcv97f5VymHcryTJ8vzGsC-d4cLp9kBQGS25ztxO5c8o3M87ypF8qAQCTdqTkG8pTmllM0X8Q-VKKcfJ9iIA)